How can I download Azure Blobs by URL with Active Directory Authentication with react?
Yes, it looks very familiar as: How can I access Azure Blobs by URL with Active Directory authentication?
However, I have no need to show them as img href directly, the react app can download the file first and then show it.
We have a separate service that is uploading images. Not able to generate SAS-tokens. This all works fine. I have users authenticated via AAD (or should I say Entra ;) ).
We have a lot of images that we want to display, but only for the users that are authenticated, so I was working against this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory.
I have given myself the storage reader role and assigned it to myself.
Then request a token like: az account get-access-token --resource https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net (the storage account, but not specifying the container)
However, if I use that bearer token I always receive a 403 on a GET:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:539cf90f-901e-0012-2b10-f3ae03000000
Time:2024-08-20T14:48:46.0263916Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Authentication scheme Bearer is not supported in this version.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>

If I look at the token it looks good, JWT.MS verified etc.
I use the URL that is stated from the blob item.
If I generate a SAS-token and append it, it works, my problem here is that it will remain working if the user is also not authenticated anymore, that is not allowed.
What piece am I missing?

There was a solution provided in this thread: AzureStorage Blob Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature
x-ms-version: 2017-11-09
Which I added now, and it works. I have to lookup some details on this, but at least I have something working.
